# Proving $ \frac{1}{n!n}>\sum _{k=n+1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k!} $

Tags: calculus

> I'm trying to prove this inequality:
> $$ \frac{1}{n!n}>\sum _{k=n+1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k!} $$

The only thing I could come up with is this (Please at least try to not laugh).

For example, if we take $n=1$, then $\frac{1}{n!n}=1$. I couldn't find what sum of $\sum _{k=n+1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k!}$ would be when $n=1$, so I compared it to a series that I know will be equal to $1$, namely $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} $.
I compared the first few terms of $ \sum _{k=n+1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k!}$ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} $. They are $ (\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}\:+...) $ and $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}\:+...)$ respectively. We see that the first terms of both series are same but after that the trerms of the first series are smaller than those the second. So, if the second series amounts to $1$, then the first series must be smaller than 1. So we have $ \frac{1}{n!n} = 1 $ and $ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k!} < 1 $ when $n=1$. Then we could take derivatives of both sides that is $ \frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{1}{n!n}\right) $ and $ \frac{d}{dn}\left(\sum \:_{k=n+1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{k!}\right) $ and see if the derivative left hand side is less than that of the right hand side then the inequality holds for all $n > 1$. But we can't take derivatives of factorials right ? So this method won't work.

Comment: I think the power series of $e^x$ might be helpful here

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going with the derivatives... $ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{n!n}\right) =\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum \:_{k=n+1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{k!}\right)=0.$

Comment: I changed it from $\frac{d}{dx}\left(...\right) $ to $ \frac{d}{dn}\left(...\right) $

Comment: How would you differentiate the factorial function? That's not exactly a trivial thing.

Comment: That's the point, I can't differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the simple idea $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k!}=\frac1{(n+1)!}\sum_{h=0}^\infty \frac1{\prod_{j=1}^h(n+1+j)}\le\frac1{(n+1)!}\sum_{h=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+2)^h}=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)!(n+1)}$$

And then you only need to verify that $\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}<\frac1n$.